# NIntegrate Which Includes a Definite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I need to calculate a numerical integral which consists of the following functions:

```
f7 := 1/
   (Pi^8*(
   (1/8)*(y0 + y1 + y2 + y3 - y4 - y5 - y6 - y7)^2 + 1)
   *
   ((1/8)*(y0 + y1 - y2 - y3 + y4 + y5 - y6 - y7)^2 + 1)
   *
   ((1/8)*(y0 - y1 + y2 - y3 + y4 - y5 + y6 - y7)^2 + 1)
   *
   ((1/8)*(y0 - y1 - y2 + y3 - y4 + y5 + y6 - y7)^2 + 1)
   *
   ((1/8)*(y0 - y1 - y2 + y3 + y4 - y5 - y6 + y7)^2 + 1)
   *
   ((1/8)*(y0 - y1 + y2 - y3 - y4 + y5 - y6 + y7)^2 + 1)
   *
   ((1/8)*(y0 + y1 - y2 - y3 - y4 - y5 + y6 + y7)^2 + 1)
   *
   ((1/8)*(y0 + y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6 + y7)^2 + 1))

f6 := Integrate[f7, {y7, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {Element[{y0, y1, y2,  y3, y4, y5, y6},Reals]}]


h7 = NIntegrate[f7*Log[f7/f6], {y0, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y1, 
 -Infinity, Infinity}, {y2, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
{y3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y4, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
{y5, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y6, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
{y7, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

My question here is, f6 is hard to calculate symbolically. However, I only need h7.  Is there any way to calculate h7 using NIntegrate without trying to calculate f6 symbolically?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Don't use subscripts. `Subscript[y, 1]` doesn't create a variable $y_1$, it takes a variable `y` that is inside a two-argument function `Subscript`. Compute the following to see what I mean: `D[Subscript[y, 1], y]`. Use simply `y1`, `y2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the multiple Integral completeley with NIntegrate. Try this code:

```
    In[31]:= f7[y0_, y1_, y2_, y3_, y4_, y5_, y6_, y7_] = 
    1/(Pi^8*((1/8)*(y0 + y1 + y2 + y3 - y4 - y5 - y6 - y7)^2 + 
   1)*((1/8)*(y0 + y1 - y2 - y3 + y4 + y5 - y6 - y7)^2 + 
   1)*((1/8)*(y0 - y1 + y2 - y3 + y4 - y5 + y6 - y7)^2 + 
   1)*((1/8)*(y0 - y1 - y2 + y3 - y4 + y5 + y6 - y7)^2 + 
   1)*((1/8)*(y0 - y1 - y2 + y3 + y4 - y5 - y6 + y7)^2 + 
   1)*((1/8)*(y0 - y1 + y2 - y3 - y4 + y5 - y6 + y7)^2 + 
   1)*((1/8)*(y0 + y1 - y2 - y3 - y4 - y5 + y6 + y7)^2 + 
   1)*((1/8)*(y0 + y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6 + y7)^2 + 1));



In[32]:= f6[y0_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, y2_?NumericQ, y3_?NumericQ, 
 y4_?NumericQ, y5_?NumericQ, y6_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
f7[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7], {y7, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
MaxRecursion -> 100]

(h7 = NIntegrate[
f7[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7]*
 Log[f7[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7]/
   f6[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6]], {y0, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y2, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y4, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y5, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y6, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y7, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
MaxRecursion -> 20]) // Timing

      NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy     
      GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global 
 error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of 
integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working    precision 
is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly
 oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value
 of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option 
MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. 
NIntegrate obtained -7.47918 and 4.45574566213166` for the integral  and 
error estimates. >>


 {50349.7, -7.47918}

   In[33]:= (h7 = 
   NIntegrate[
f7[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7]*
 Log[f7[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7]/
   f6[y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6]], {y0, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y2, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y4, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y5, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y6, -Infinity, 
 Infinity}, {y7, -Infinity, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 100, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, 
  Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}]) // Timing

Out[33]= $Aborted
```

Use ?NumericQ for dhe definition of f6 in order to force it to be evaluated only when it has got numerical values from the h7 - Integration.

I first got a result with a very large error after one day of calculation
on a intel i7 4790 Processor.
To get a better result, you should try the code wiht higher MaxErrorIncreases. 
Attention:This may take a few days of calculation.